# to run autosys command with start argument in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

how I can execute autosys command with start argument,  on linux server: when I do:service autosys start
it does not work, I can only do it from /etc/init.d: ./waae_agent-autosys_dev start|stop|restart

in ansible playbook when I write:  shell: "/etc/init.d/waae_agent-autosys_dev restart"

it does not start it, but it is the only way how we start it from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- name: "Restart waae_agent-autosys_dev"
  service:
    name: waae_agent-autosys_dev
    state: restarted
```